# Не выводится окно Kivy

Tags: kivy

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class BoxApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button()

if __name__ == "main":
    BoxApp().run()
```

Не выводится окно Kivy. Сто раз уже все переустанавливал.

Консоль:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\temna\.kivy\logs\kivy_20-05-17_22.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.1.12
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.1.23
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at 
"C:\Users\temna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.7 (tags/v3.7.7:d7c567b08f, Mar 10 2020, 10:41:24) [MSC v.1900 64 bit 
(AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at 
"C:\Users\temna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас в условии `"main"`, а надо с двумя нижними подчеркиваниями по обеим сторонам `"__main__"`.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class BoxApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    BoxApp().run()
```